# How to query another tables when Loop a records collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to loop a collection of records, and check the answers status from another tables. The detail describle in the **View** part.

### Model

```
# Quiz

class Quiz < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :quiz_questions
  has_many :questions, :through => :quiz_questions

  has_many :quiz_details
end

# QuizDetail
class QuizDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz
end

# QuizQuestion
class QuizQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :question
end
```

### Controller

```
# quiz_questions_controller.rb

def index
  @questions = @quiz.questions
  # @quiz_details = @quiz.quiz_details
end
```

### DB

```
create_table "quiz_details", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "quiz_id"
  t.integer  "question_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.boolean  "is_correct",  default: false
  t.datetime "created_at",                  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                  null: false
end
```

### View

```
<ul>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li>

      # I want to check the answers status
      # The status in the quiz_details table
      # `is_correct` : true or false

      <%= link_to question.title, quiz_question_path(@quiz, question) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I want to know if there is a way to do this clearly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some more associations to make this work smoothly.  If I am reading your database table correctly, `quiz_details` also belongs to `questions`.  You can add that association as follows:

Add to your **Models**

```
# Question
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :quiz_details do 
    def by_quiz(quiz)
      where(quiz_id: quiz.id) 
    end
  end
end

# QuizDetail
class QuizDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :question
end
```

In your **Controller**

```
  def index
    # If you iterate over questions use this:
    @questions = @quiz.questions.includes(:quiz_details)

    # If you iterate over quiz_details use this:
    @quiz_details = @quiz.quiz_details.includes(:question)
  end
```

In your **View**

If you definitely need to iterate over `questions`:

```
<ul>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <li>
      <%= question.quiz_details(@quiz).first.is_correct %>
      <%= link_to question.title, quiz_question_path(@quiz, question) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

However, this will likely generate a nasty N+1 query that is inefficient.  You can check your console to see if it does.

A better approach is to iterate over `quiz_details` if possible:

```
<ul>
  <% @quiz_details.each do |detail| %>
    <li>
      <%= detail.is_correct %>
      <%= link_to detail.question.title, quiz_question_path(@quiz, detail.question) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```